# Integral of $(1 - x)^k x^j$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Suppose I have the following integral
$$\int_a^1 (1 - x)^k x^j dx.$$
I can compute this somewhat tediously by using the binomial theorem on the $(1 - x)^k$ term and expanding, but I'm wondering if this is some sort of known special function or if there's an easier way of computing this.

Comment: It is $B(j + 1,k + 1) - B_a (j + 1,k + 1)$. See https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17

Comment: ^^ that.
Also presumably $a$ needs to be between $0$ and $1$ in order to invoke beta functions

Comment: Yeah, a is positive. Thanks so much for the quick and simple reply!